# How to split a huge folder?

Tags: windows, powershell, dos

We have a folder on Windows that's ... huge. I ran "dir > list.txt". The command lost response after 1.5 hours. The output file is about 200 MB. It shows there're at least 2.8 million files. I know the situation is stupid but let's focus the problem itself. If I have such a folder, how can I split it to some "manageable" sub-folders? Surprisingly all the solutions I have come up with all involve getting all the files in the folder at some point, which is a no-no in my case. Any suggestions?

Thank Keith Hill and Mehrdad. I accepted Keith's answer because that's exactly what I wanted to do but I couldn't quite get PS working quickly.

With Mehrdad's tip, I wrote this little program. It took 7+ hours to move 2.8 million files. So the initial dir command did finish. But somehow it didn't return to console.

```
namespace SplitHugeFolder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var destination = args[1];

            if (!Directory.Exists(destination))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);

            var di = new DirectoryInfo(args[0]);

            var batchCount = int.Parse(args[2]);
            int currentBatch = 0;

            string targetFolder = GetNewSubfolder(destination);

            foreach (var fileInfo in di.EnumerateFiles())
            {
                if (currentBatch == batchCount)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("New Batch...");
                    currentBatch = 0;
                    targetFolder = GetNewSubfolder(destination);
                }

                var source = fileInfo.FullName;
                var target = Path.Combine(targetFolder, fileInfo.Name);
                File.Move(source, target);
                currentBatch++;
            }
        }

        private static string GetNewSubfolder(string parent)
        {
            string newFolder;
            do
            {
                newFolder = Path.Combine(parent, Path.GetRandomFileName());
            } while (Directory.Exists(newFolder));
            Directory.CreateDirectory(newFolder);
            return newFolder;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh... write your own implementation of NTFS and have it split up the `$INDEX_ALLOCATION` binary search tree? Have fun though...

Comment: By the way, why can't you get a list of all the files? Does the `FindNextFile` function also consume so much time/resources, or is it just `dir` that does that?

Comment: @Mehrdad, because it's just too slow. FindNextFile seems promising. Will try that.

Comment: @Kai: `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` are obviously functions (and not programs or DOS commands), so you'd need to write a program for them; I don't think they consume resources for enumerating big directories. But if they do, do mention that, since you can also use `NtQueryDirectoryFile` which is lower-level and has more options and control over what data is returned.

Comment: @Mehrdad, thanks for the tip, that's the way to go. There's also a managed version in .NET 4 as well. It is DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles. I wrote a little app and it seems to move forward. :)

Comment: @Kai: Great; glad it helped! I hadn't heard of EnumerateFiles; it seems interesting. :)

Comment: You can also do this "dumb": just get the first n files (say, 100k -- you can kill iterating past this, etc, or do it post-mortem), move them, get the next n files, move them, etc. Next is just coming up with the directory partition strategy.

Comment: @pst: The problem was actually *getting* the first n files, since tools that look at the entire directory won't work.

Comment: @Mehrdad "post-mortem" ;-) But it sounds like there is a much better solution. Cheers.

Comment: When you have a list of files, you don't need to list them again, right? Or is it a general question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use Get-ChildItem to index my whole C: drive every night into c:\filelist.txt. That's about 580,000 files and the resulting file size is ~60MB.  Admittedly I'm on Win7 x64 with 8 GB of RAM.  That said, you might try something like this:

```
md c:\newdir
Get-ChildItem C:\hugedir -r | 
    Foreach -Begin {$i = $j = 0} -Process { 
        if ($i++ % 100000 -eq 0) { 
            $dest = "C:\newdir\dir$j"
            md $dest
            $j++ 
        }
        Move-Item $_ $dest 
    }
```

The key is to do the move in a streaming manner. That is, don't collect up all the Get-ChildItem results into a single variable and then proceed.  That would require all 2.8 million FileInfos to be in memory at once.  Also, if you use the `Name` parameter on Get-ChildItem it will output a single string containing the file's path relative to the base dir.  Even then, perhaps this size will just overwhelm the memory available to you. And no doubt, it will take quite a while to execute.  IIRC correctly, my indexing script takes several hours.

If it does work, you should wind up with `c:\newdir\dir0` thru `dir28` but then again, I haven't tested this script at all so your mileage may vary.  BTW this approach assumes that you're huge dir is a pretty flat dir.

**Update:** Using the `Name` parameter is almost twice as slow so don't use that parameter.

Comment: This is what I wanted to do initially with PS - pipe Get-ChildItem output. Another reason to start learning PS. Thanks!

Comment: And yes, the huge folder is flat. That's what caused the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I found out the `GetChildItem` is the slowest option when working with many items in a directory.

Look at the results:

```
Measure-Command { Get-ChildItem C:\Windows -rec | Out-Null }
TotalSeconds      : 77,3730275
Measure-Command { listdir C:\Windows | Out-Null } 
TotalSeconds      : 20,4077132
measure-command { cmd /c dir c:\windows /s /b | out-null }
TotalSeconds      : 13,8357157
```

(with listdir function defined like this:

```
function listdir($dir) {
    $dir
    [system.io.directory]::GetFiles($dir)
    foreach ($d in [system.io.directory]::GetDirectories($dir)) {
        listdir $d
    }
}
```

)

With this in mind, what I would do: I would stay in PowerShell but use more lowlevel approach with .NET methods:

```
function DoForFirst($directory, $max, $action) {
    function go($dir, $options)
    {
        foreach ($f in [system.io.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($dir))
        {
            if ($options.Remaining -le 0) { return }
            & $action $f
            $options.Remaining--
        }
        foreach ($d in [system.io.directory]::EnumerateDirectories($dir))
        {
            if ($options.Remaining -le 0) { return }
            go $d $options
        }
    }
    go $directory (New-Object PsObject -Property @{Remaining=$max })
}
doForFirst c:\windows 100 {write-host File: $args }
# I use PsObject to avoid global variables and ref parameters.
```

*To use the code you have to switch to .NET 4.0 runtime -- enumerating methods are new in .NET 4.0.*

You can specify any scriptblock as `-action` parameter, so in your case it would be something like `{Move-item -literalPath $args -dest c:\dir }`.

Just try to list first 1000 items, I hope it will finish very quickly:

```
doForFirst c:\yourdirectory 1000 {write-host '.' -nonew }
```

And of course you can process all items at once, just use

```
doForFirst c:\yourdirectory ([long]::MaxValue) {move-item ... }
```

and each item should be processed immediately after it is returned. So the whole list is not read at once and then processed, but it is processed during reading.

Comment: It gets worse.  At about 300000 files, the resonse time graph goes hockey-stick http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/11/04/why-is-get-childitem-so-slow.aspx

Comment: Keep in mind that EnumerateFiles is a new method in .NET 4.0 and not normally available to PowerShell. You must have mod'd your PowerShell config or registry to bind PowerShell to .NET 4.0.

Comment: Also, when you look at this you have to examine memory usage as well as speed. I would prefer something that took 4 hours but completed to something that is faster initially but dies due to insufficient memory.  For example, [io.directory]::GetFiles() returns an array of *all* of the files.  This would most likely cause problems in the OP's scenario.

Comment: @Keith, added info about .NET 4.0 (I used the config method). As for the reliability - function `listdir` is not efficient. It has to take result from each recursive call and append it to current array. Reallocating, more memory, ... But the approach with `EnumerateFiles` should be imho much more cpu/memory efficient than `Get-ChildItem`, because 1) it doesn't fetch file infos and 2) uses new method which is not true with `Get-ChildItem` based on .NET 2.0.

Comment: @stej, yep, have to agree about the `EnumerateFiles` approach.  Hopefully the next version of PowerShell is based on .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

How about starting with this:
    cmd /c dir /b > list.txt

That should get you a list of all the file names.

If you're doing "dir > list.txt" from a powershell prompt, get-childitem is aliased as "dir". Get-childitem has known issues enumerating large directories, and the object collections it returns can get huge.

Comment: I wasn't running from PS. It's a plain DOS dir. It died after getting 2.8M files. I haven't tried but my guess is dir /b works similarly.

Comment: It will return only the file names.<br>19.0795682

Comment: (measure-command {cmd /c dir c:\windows /s}).totalseconds 3.6437911 (measure-command {cmd /c dir c:\windows /b /s}).totalseconds 2.6323411   Faster, but not by much.